# Is $F(x)$ the same as $\bigcup\{y\mid \langle x, y\rangle\;\in F\}$?

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory

According to "Elements of Set Theory" by Enderton 43p,

> For a function $F$ and a point $x$ in dom $F$, the unique $y$ such that $_xF_y$ is called the *value* of $F$ at $x$ and is denoted $F(x)$. Thus $\langle x, F(x)\rangle\;\in F$. The "$F(x)$" notation was introduced by Euler in the 1700s. We hereby resolve to use this notation *only* when $F$ is a function and $x\in dom\;F$. There are, however, some artificial ways of defining $F(x)$ that are meaningful for any $F$ and $x$. For example, the set
> $$\bigcup\{y\;\mid\langle x, y\rangle\;\in F\}$$
> is equal to $F(x)$ whenever $F$ is a function and $x\in dom\;F$.

I think $\bigcup\{y\;\mid\langle x, y\rangle\;\in F\}$ should be $\{y\;|\langle x, y\rangle\;\in F\}$. What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice that $\{y\mid\langle x, y\rangle\;\in F\}$ is a set whose elements are those $y$ such that $\langle x,y\rangle\in F$.  There is only one such $y$, namely $F(x)$, so this is a set with $F(x)$ as its only element; that is, it is the set $\{F(x)\}$.

But we don't want the set $\{F(x)\}$, we want just $F(x)$ itself!  The trick now is to apply the union operator.  The union $\bigcup\{F(x)\}$ is exactly $F(x)$ itself, since you are taking the union of all the elements of the set $\{F(x)\}$ and the only such element is $F(x)$.  In other words, when applied to a singleton set, the union operator "extracts" the single element out of the set.

Answer (score 0):

It's the same.  I guess the more common/less confusing notation would be $\bigcup \{\{y\} \, \mid \, \langle x,y \rangle \in F\}$.  In general, sometimes people write $\bigcup \{E \, \mid \, E \in \mathscr{E}\}$ for $\bigcup_{E \in \mathscr{E}} E$, particularly when they don't want to bother defining $\mathscr{E}$.  I don't like this notation, but it's pretty common.

**Edit:** Here is an example of this notation in action.  In [this](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1805.08278.pdf) paper, $H$ and $P$ are the half-space and paraboloid defined by
\begin{align*}
H &= \left\{x \in \mathbb{R}^{d} \, \mid \, x_{d} > 0\right\}, \\
P &= \left\{x \in \mathbb{R}^{d} \, \mid \, x_{d} > \frac{1}{2} (x_{1}^{2} + \dots + x_{d - 1}^{2})\right\}.
\end{align*}
and, for a given $X \subseteq H$, the *semi-convex hull* of $X$ is defined by --- and here I use the notation of the paper ---
\begin{equation*}
\text{semi}(X) = H \setminus \bigcup \left\{ x - P \, \mid \, x \in H, \, \, (x - P) \cap X = \emptyset \right\}.
\end{equation*}
See Section 2.1 of the paper (currently the last line of page 10). Just to be clear, let me clarify that $x - P$ denotes the set $\{x - y \, \mid \, y \in P\} \subseteq \mathbb{R}^{d}$.

What does this mean?  My preferred notation would be the following.  First, define $\mathcal{X}(X) \subseteq H$ by
\begin{equation*}
\mathcal{X}(X) = \{x \in H \, \mid \, (x - P) \cap X = \emptyset\}.
\end{equation*}
Next, $\text{semi}(X)$ is the set
\begin{equation*}
\text{semi}(X) = H \setminus \bigcup_{x \in \mathcal{X}(X)} (x - P).
\end{equation*}
As you can see, the first way of writing the union does not require defining $\mathcal{X}(X)$ so is a bit more economical (and arguably less pedantic).  Don't get me wrong: again, I prefer the second way (and openly admit to being a pedant).

Finally, in the comments, people have asked: why do I suggest $\bigcup \{ \{y\} \, \mid \, \langle x, y \rangle \in F\}$ would be less confusing?  It's just like in the example I gave.  $\bigcup \{x - P \, \mid \, x \in H, \, \, (x - P) \cap X = \emptyset\}$ is *not* meant to be the "set of sets" $\{x - P \, \mid \, x \in \mathcal{X}(X)\}$, it is meant to be the union of those sets.  In other words, the extra set of braces is meant to encode what we're unioning over, not that we are looking at "sets of sets."  (Again, this is not my preferred notation, but it's out there being used by mathematicians.)  If I apply this same logic to the OP's example, then I would want to see $\bigcup \{\{y\} \, \mid \, \langle x,y \rangle \in F\}$ rather than $\bigcup \{y \, \mid \, \langle x,y \rangle \in F\}$.  Again, all of this is to be consistent with the convention that $\bigcup \{E \, \mid \, E \in \mathscr{E}\}$ is understood as $\bigcup_{E \in \mathscr{E}} E$.

My reasoning, in other words, is that you would write $\bigcup_{\langle x, y\rangle \in F} \{y\}$, not $\bigcup_{\langle x, y \rangle \in F} y$, which I suspect will not be a controversial claim.

Comment: But $\{\{1, 2\}, \{1, 3\}\} \not = \{1, 2, 3\} = \bigcup\{\{1, 2\}, \{1, 3\}\}$. I don't understand they are the same. What am I still missing..?

Comment: $\bigcup \{\{y\} \, \mid \, \langle x,y \rangle \in F\}$ is wrong, though: that would output $\{F(x)\}$, not $F(x)$.

Comment: See my edits.  @EricWofsey, consider the very last paragraph of the edit, in particular.

Comment: But $\bigcup_{\langle x, y\rangle \in F} \{y\}=\{F(x)\}$, not $F(x)$!  After all, you're taking a union of a bunch of singleton sets (in this case, just one), so the result will be a set which contains all the elements of those singleton sets (in this case, just one, namely $F(x)$).  The whole point here is that (strange as it might seem) you *want* to take the union $\bigcup_{\langle x, y \rangle \in F} y$.

Comment: @EricWofsey, OK, I see what you're saying now.